Left ctrl and left shift keys works for a moment only when I keep pressed the Windows key
I've already tried several options. Turning off filter keys, reinstall drivers, restart, etc. I'm using Windows 11. What could be the issue?
Laptop: MSI Katana GF66 12UE

You need to determine if it is a keyboard issue or software issue. Try a different keyboard to figure this out. If the problem persists on a different keyboard the issue is with your computer's software. If the problem goes away, the problem is with the first keyboard. This is pretty much the first and basic step after you've checked the software things you say you've tried.

Yes, I don't have another keyboard at the moment. However I suspect is a software related problem

Cheap keyboards are cheap. Your neighbor probably has a keyboard you can borrow for a couple minutes. This is the next step. You've already tried the basic software issues. You may help us more by giving us more details, such as your computer model and software, the keyboard type/model, etc. But really, if you have done what you've said you've done, your next step is to swap the keyboard.

check for debris under the keytops

the description of the problem is unclear ... do the keys work normally if the Win key is not pressed? ... please update your post

If you don't have another keyboard to test with, you could also try booting to a Linux live USB drive to isolate the problem to Windows or your hardware. Also, if the problem is related to key rollover, I have found Keyboard Test Utility helpful for showing which keys are being pressed and released.
